# How to expand logical volume on existing physical volume on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, lvm

nvme0n1p3 has 8.5G, ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv has 4G. How can I expand ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv to 8G?

```
 NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
nvme0n1                   259:0    0   10G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0  8.5G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    4G  0 lvm  /
```

When I try to do
`vgextend ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv /dev/nvme0n1p3`
it says

```
Physical volume '/dev/nvme0n1p3' is already in volume group 'ubuntu-vg'
Unable to add physical volume '/dev/nvme0n1p3' to volume group 'ubuntu-vg'
  /dev/nvme0n1p3: physical volume not initialized.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure is relatively sample. First you need to extend the LV:

```
lvextend -L+1GB /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

The last command add 1 GB space to `/`
and then extend your filesystem. If it's ext4 use command:

```
resize2fs /
```

If its XFS you can use command

```
xfs_growfs -d /
```

Both resize commands can be done on the fly (w/o unmount the filesystem)

Comment: `lvextend` has a option to resize the file system as part of growing the LV. Use `-r` or `--resizefs`.

Comment: @doneal24, never used and prefer one command, one function :)

Comment: Is creating a larger usable file system on disk one function that can be done in one command? The UNIX philosophy is good overall but can be taken too far. Not criticism as I generally agree with you here but should we tell newcomers not to use parted because all of its features can be duplicated with fdisk and file system utilities?

Comment: @doneal24, for some cases I agree with you, but in this particular I prefer to be more conservative :)

Comment: @doneal24 Because of how it handles the resize, `lvextend` is not guaranteed to be able to resize arbitrary filesystems. IIRC, right now it only properly supports ext*, XFS, and ReiserFS. By just choosing to do the resize yourself, you avoid having to deal with such issues.